# Meaning of 난 in 해가지고난후

Tags: grammar

I just encountered the phrase:

**해가지고난후**

In which I interpreted as *After the sun sets.*

해가지다 means sunset, and 후 means after. I also understand that the connecting particle 고 is like "and" in English. My question is that what is the purpose of 난 in the sentence? I know it is a shortened 나는 meaning "I" but what does it mean in the phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-고 나다 (and also -고 난) are function words there. You can disassemble **해가 지고 난 후** as follows:

- 해: a noun meaning "the sun"
- 가: a subject marker attached to 체언 that ends without 받침
- 지다 (**stem**: 지): a verb meaning "(for the star, planet, or moon) to set"
- -고: a connective **ending** *attached to the main verb* and *required by the following (auxiliary) verb*
- [나다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=62134) in -고 나다 (**stem**: 나): an auxiliary verb used when the subject having completed the action of the preceding statement
- [-ㄴ](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=78634): an **ending** of a word that makes the preceding statement function as an **adnominal** and indicates an event or action having occurred in the past
- 후: a **noun** meaning "a later time"

Thus, the verb 나다 requires another verb before it in a specific construction with the ending -고. You should keep in mind that a lot of verbs require certain grammatical constructions and have multiple meanings.